# Simplify foreach iterate after properties in C#

Tags: c#

How I can simplify foreach in this particular situation?

```
foreach (var product in Produkty.Model)
{                
    product.Price0 += Math.Round((product.Price0 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price1 += Math.Round((product.Price1 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price2 += Math.Round((product.Price2 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price3 += Math.Round((product.Price3 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price4 += Math.Round((product.Price4 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price5 += Math.Round((product.Price5 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price6 += Math.Round((product.Price6 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price7 += Math.Round((product.Price7 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price8 += Math.Round((product.Price8 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
    product.Price9 += Math.Round((product.Price9 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);
}
```

Comment: Easily? Use reflection. Efficiently? Use reflection to pre-compile accessor delegates. Efficiently and correctly? Maybe use an array instead of individual properties.

Comment: Or make the prices an enumerable collection and iterate through those instead of having 10 hard coded properties, which seems a poor design choice.

Comment: And of course, you still need to demonstrate how this is not sufficient for your situation as is.

Comment: @Trey makes a very good point.  However if you do not wish to use reflection or make an enumerable instead of hard coded properties you could at least refactor your math logic into a separate method so you're not repeating yourself.

Comment: @maccettura Good call.

Comment: Unroll the outer loop, too.

Comment: First thing you want to do is turn `Math.Round((product.Price0 ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);` into a function, where `product.PriceX` is a parameter. That will simplify your code tremendously.

Comment: Unrolling loops isn't used to make code cleaner... it's used to make them faster.  Unrolling will make this even more complex.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer No, this question is off-topic here. Working code looking for an improvement belongs on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Func<double?, double> calc = 
    p => Math.Round((p ?? 0) * (countValue / oldCountValue), accuracyValue);

foreach (var product in Produkty.Model)
{
    product.Price0 += calc(product.Price0);
    product.Price1 += calc(product.Price1);
    // ... rinse and repeat.
}
```

Comment: Something like this :) thank u

Comment: Who knows... he might be using decimal.  I was lazy and just used double because I simply didn't care.

Comment: @DavidL I don't know why someone or many flagged my comment, but it's not irrelevant. I wouldn't provide a flawed answer. Using floats to store financial is one of worst decisions since ages... And while the OP found that your answer solved the issue, really Metthew is just encapsulating the calculation. I would have found an approach to avoid the `Price0`, `PriceN` thing...

Comment: OP wanted a way to clean up code.  He didn't ask for a full code review.

Comment: I use decimal :)